# Does Javascript support any special syntax to support performance testing?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, performance-testing

I need to track how long many processes take and so my code looks like this:

```
console.log("Doing thing 1");
var startTime = performance.now();
var thing = doThing()
times.loadTime = performance.now() - startTime;

console.log("Doing thing 2");
startTime = performance.now();
var thing2 = doOtherThing();
var endTime = performance.now();
times.thingTime2 = endTime - startTime;

console.log("Doing thing 3");
var thing3 = doThing3();
ties.thingTime3 = performance.now() - endTime;
```

As you can guess, this is getting hard to read.

I know that in my current environment I can use things like:

```
console.startTime();
console.startTime("Thing 1");
console.endTime();
```

And so on. See the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) object.

But I think I've seen something where javascript code was using blocks or labels like this:

```
thing1 {
   var thing = doThing()
}

thing2 {
    var thing2 = doOtherThing();
}

thing3 {
    var thing3 = doThing3();
}

// desired result { name: "thing1", startTime: 0, endTime: 10 }
console.log(thing1);
```

Or labels:

```
thing1:
    var thing = doThing()
end
```

These look much more readable to me.

Is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in like that, but something that could help would be to write a function wrapper around `performance.now` calls.

```js
const times = [];
const measure = (cb) => {
  const startTime = performance.now();
  const result = cb();
  times.push(performance.now() - startTime);
  return result;
};

const thing = measure(() => ({ thing1: 'foo' }));
const thing2 = measure(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++);
  return { thing2: 'foo' };
});
const thing3 = measure(() => ({ thing3: 'foo' }));
console.log(times);
```

or

```js
const times = [];
const measure = (name, cb) => {
  const startTime = performance.now();
  const result = cb();
  times.push({ name, time: performance.now() - startTime });
  return result;
};

const thing = measure('thing', () => ({ thing1: 'foo' }));
const thing2 = measure('thing2', () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++);
  return { thing2: 'foo' };
});
const thing3 = measure('thing3', () => ({ thing3: 'foo' }));
console.log(times);
```

-

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with `console.timeEnd` - it's overly verbose and it's not easily removable in production builds. I prefer to have a shortcut like this in my projects:

```
const T = (name='') => {
    T.timers = T.timers || []

    if (name)
        T.timers.push([name, performance.now()])
    else {
        let end = performance.now()
        let [name, start] = T.timers.pop()
        console.log('TIMER:', name,  (end - start).toFixed(3))
    }
}
```

Then, you can do something like

```
T('step1')
for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    heavy stuff
}
T()

T('step2')
for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    more heavy stuff
}
T()
```

and so on.

For production builds you can easily turn `T` into a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function like this

```
const useMeasure = (fn) => {
    const start = performance.now();
    const res = fn();
    const end = performance.now();
    return [res, end - start];
}
```

it returns the result of the function as well as the time it took to complete.

you can use it like this:-

```
function count() {
    let cnt = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}

const [result, timeTaken] = useMeasure(count);

console.log(result, timeTaken);
```

if your function takes arguments you can edit it like this so that you can also pass your args:-

```
const useMeasureWithArgs = (fn, ...args) => {
    const start = performance.now();
    const res = fn(...args);
    const end = performance.now();
    return [res, end - start];
}
```

and use it like this:-

```
function countUpTo(x) {
    let cnt = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}

const [result, timeTaken] = useMeasureWithArgs(countUpTo, 1000);

console.log(result, timeTaken);
```

Comment: often it's necessary to profile particular snippets (few lines of code) rather than whole functions, e.g. when optimizing a long function which you already know to be slow. A function like posted doesn't help with that.